# Pandas overlapped time intervals to time series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, time-series

I have a pandas dataframe that includes time intervals that overlapping at some points (figure 1). I need a data frame that has a time series that starts beginning from the first start_time to the end of the last end_time (figure 2).
I have to sum up VIS values at overlapped time intervals.
I couldn't figure it out. How can I do it?

[image]

[image]

Comment: cross merge and query.

Comment: I have found some similar topics but there were a few answers and they didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

This problem is easily solved with the python package [staircase](https://www.staircase.dev), which is built on pandas and numpy for the purposes of working with (mathematical) step functions.

Assume your original dataframe is called `df` and the times you want in your resulting dataframe are an array (or datetime index, or series etc) called `times`.

```
import staircase as sc

stepfunction = sc.Stairs(df, start="start_time", end="end_time", value="VIS")
result = stepfunction(times, include_index=True)
```

That's it, `result` is a pandas Series indexed by times, and has the values you want.  You can convert it to a dataframe in the format you want using `reset_index` method on the Series.

You can generate your `times` data like this

```
import pandas as pd

times = pd.date_range(df["start_time"].min(), df["end_time"].max(), freq="30min")
```

**Why it works**

Each row in your dataframe can be thought of a step function.  For example the first row corresponds to a step function which starts with a value of zero, then at `2002-02-03 04:15:00` increases to a value of 10, then at `2002-02-04 04:45:00` returns to zero.  When you sum all the step functions up for each row you have one step function whose value is the sum of all VIS values at any point.  This is what has been assigned to the `stepfunction` variable above.  The `stepfunction` variable is callable, and returns values of the step function at the points specified.  This is what is happening in the last line of the example where the `result` variable is being assigned.

**note**:
I am the creator of staircase.  Please feel free to reach out with feedback or questions if you have any.

Comment: Interesting approach.

Answer (score 0):

If you paste your data instead of the images, I'd be able to test this. But this is how you may want to think about it. Assume your dataframe is called df.

```
df['start_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['start_time']) # in case it's not datetime already
df.set_index('start_time', inplace=True)
new_dates = pd.date_range(start=min(df.index), end=max(df.end_time), freq='15Min')
new_df = df.reindex(new_dates, fill_value=np.nan)
```

As long as there are no duplicates in start_time, this should work. If there is, that'd need to be handled in some other way.

Resample is another possibility, but without data, it's tough to say what would work.